# angular : jasmine call the subscribe function

Tags: angular, jasmine

This is the ts code

```
 handleSave () {
    this.save.showModal();

    this.gridService
        .handleSave(this)
        .subscribe((request) => this.saveProgressModalComponent.progress(request));

  }
```

This is the jasmine code.

```
class GridServiceMock {
    public dirtySubject : BehaviorSubject<any> = new BehaviorSubject(false);
    public gridCellUpdated                     = false;
    public changeHash : any                    = {};
    handleChange(id, data, row, value) {
    }
    handleSave(gridComponent){

    }
}

 { provide : GridService,useClass : GridServiceMock},

it(
      'should handle save', () => {
        const modalSpy = spyOn(component['saveProgressModalComponent'], 'showModal').and.returnValue(true);
    let result;
    const gridSpy = spyOn(component['gridService'], 'handleSave').and.callFake(function(component) {
          return {
            then: (response) => result = response
          };
        });
        component.handleSave();
        expect(modalSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
        expect(gridSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
      }
    );
```

Error:

```
Error: <spyOn> : handleSave() method does not exist
```

Comment: is the handlesave method on the component public?

Comment: No, it was private. I updated my code. Still, the error is same.

Comment: why do you need to `callFake`?

Comment: Well, I don't know the other way to do this.

Comment: it the `gridService` private as well?

Comment: yes, thats private as well

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156479/discussion-between-ish-and-methgaard).

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that the `gridService`is private. You cannot (and shouldn't) access private properties.

What you need to do is to provide the service and save an instance:

```
let gridService: GridService;

providers: [
 {
  provide: GridService,
  useValue: {
  handleSave: _ => {}, // or whatever needs to be returned
  },
 },


beforeEach(()=>{
 gridService = fixture.debugElement.injector.get(GridService)
});
```

now use `gridService` instead of `component['gridService']`

Comment: Now I am getting TypeError: this.gridService.handleSave(...).subscribe is not a function. I updated the code to what I did.

Comment: Are you familiar with the `TestBed`?